# Ajax request with customized parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am working on a simple webpage making a Ajax request to server to upload some images.

Suppose the webpage has multiple upload fields, so it can allow user to upload image for different purpose. Lets say, one image upload field is to upload user's mom's picture, the other field is to upload his dad's picture.

In this case, the server side needs to know which upload is for which purpose. The ajax call I am currently using is:

```
$.ajax({
    url: requestUrl,
    type: 'POST',
    success: successCallBack,
    error: errorCallBack,
    data: formData, <-- the image
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

I want to let server know if the user is sending a image for dad or mom, also I want the server know the length and format of this image, maybe some extra strings to describe this image as well. I was wondering if I could compile these information to a Json string, and sent it together with the image. I don't know where I should put all these information in this ajax call. Could someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that you have two upload buttons for uploading different type of pictures.
What you can do is probably give a data-id attribute to each button.

For example, this one is for uploading users own picture:

```
<input type="button" data-id="ownpicture" value=""></input>
```

and when you call the ajax method on click of this button, you can catch the data-id attribute in a variable, say

```
var pictureType = $(this).attr('data-id');
```

Then you can pass this value as a parameter to your method.
And on server side, you can use a switch-case to save the correct picture based on this string parameter. Make sense?

You can append additional information in formdata object like below example:

```
var fd = new FormData("Your image here");
fd.append("CustomField", "This is some extra data");
$.ajax({
url: "stash.php",
type: "POST",
data: fd,
processData: false,  
contentType: false   
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This could be a good solution if I want to distinguish between different ajax call. However, if I want to add some more customized information with this request (such as a description string or a number specify the data size), is there a consistent way of doing that?

Comment: You can append your information in Formdata object itself using Formdata.appned("key","value") method of formdata Api. I have modified the answer above.

Comment: why don you use the form plugin? it has all the options you want. http://malsup.com/jquery/form/